# Question regarding intention

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, allah, deeds

When I do a good deed should my intention should be only to do it for the sake of Allah (swt) my question is should I intent to get reward and countenance of Allah (swt) or doing it for the sake of Allah swt is enough and the reward and countenance come with doing the deed for the sake of Allah swt.

Answer (score 1):

Salaam! Doing a good deed for the sake of Allah (swt) is sufficient enough. Remember, that Allah (swt) knows what we are thinking in our heart, and if your heart is pure, you will gain the ajr iA.
Hope that helps. :)
Muslimgap